# How to add signature to PDF using PDFKit and sticker view?

Tags: swift, signature, pdfkit, pdf-annotations, pdfdocument

I am trying to add signature to PDF using PDFKit.

What I have tried:

1. add annotation as given by PDFKit framework.
2. give annotation type to signature
3. save annotation to PDFPage
   This is working fine

I have used extension to drag signature image to current PDFPage, but I can not rotate and pinch to zoom in/out it properly.

So, I have used stikerView having all this functionality (zoom, rotate, close signature view).

Problem:

1. I have to add sticker view to PDFDocument not PDFPage as its nsobject
2. So, it can move to all pages of PDF
3. I am not getting exact rotation and frame of sticker view so that I can adjust frame and rotation of Annotation in PDFKit at the time of save

What are the best practices to give signature in PDFKit